# Non-working EXE file generated at the end of compilation

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, pyinstaller

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="bb",
    version="1.2.5",
    description="asd",
    packages=find_packages(where="src"),
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    include_package_data=True,
    python_requires=">=3.7",
    install_requires=[
        "pyqt6",
        "pycryptodome",
        "keyring",
        "requests",
    ],
    entry_points={
        "gui_scripts": [
            "bb= bb.__main__:main"
        ],
    },
)
```

setup.cfg:

```
[metadata]
name = bb
version = attr: bb._version.__version__

[options]
packages = find:
package_dir =
    =src
include_package_data = true
python_requires = >=3.7
setup_requires =
  pip >= 10
install_requires =
  pyqt6
  pycryptodome
  keyring
  requests

[options.entry_points]
gui_scripts =
  bb= bb.__main__:main

[options.packages.find]
where=src
```

Root:

```
    │   .gitignore
    │   MANIFEST.in
    │   requirements.txt
    │   setup.cfg
    │   setup.py
    │   setup.spec
    │   __main__.py
    │           
    ├───design
    │       ...
    │
    │
    ├───package
    │       ...
    │
    ├───src
    │   └───bb
    │       │   __init__.py
    │       │
    │       ├───bin
    │       │   ...
    │       │
    │       ├───img
    │       │   ...
    │       │
    │       ├───misc
    │       │   ...
    │       │
    │       ├───scripts
    │       │   ...
    │       │
    │       └───ui
    │               ...
    │
    └───venv
        │   .....
```

I am compiling the project with this `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed setup.py` command. At the end of the compilation, a low-size EXE file is created and when I try to run it, it does not work and does not give an error.

During compilation, I do not see an error message in the console.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Reduce your problem to find out: read and run through the [mcve] exercise, so that even if after reducing your code to the absolute bare minimum things still don't work, you can now put that code in your post and others can reproduce the problem using your code.